# How to target .css selecor by text, Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to learn Scrapy for Python(3), writing a crawler that is supposed to get data on from swedish ecommerce-site Blocket.se.

The "next page" button on the bottom of the page is one of many buttons without a unique class or id. The only difference between the buttons is the actual element text, the tags look the same.

"Next page"-button html

```
<a class="page_nav" itemprop="name" href="?q=macbook+air&amp;cg=0&amp;w=1&amp;st=s&amp;c=&amp;ca=11&amp;l=0&amp;md=th&amp;o=2&amp;last=1">
            Nästa sida »
        </a>
```

"1st page"-button html

```
<a class="page_nav" itemprop="name" href="?q=macbook+air&amp;cg=0&amp;w=1&amp;st=s&amp;c=&amp;ca=11&amp;l=0&amp;md=th">
                    1
                </a>
```

Is there a way to specifically target the "next page"-button for the pagination part in the Scrapy code? Maybe by the actual text inside the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `response.xpath(u'//a[contains(text(), "Nästa sida")]/@href').get()`